# wamp y bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, wamp

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en plataforma window 7 Apache  y bootstrap 3 con php 5, estoy migrando a window 10 WAMP 3.1.7 64 bit y php 7 y me da este error

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Alguien de la comunidad puede indicarme que hacer ?

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Compártenos algo de código frontend para ver cómo realiza las peticiones tu aplicación y podremos orientarte para migrarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que convertir todas las peticiones `XMLHttpRequest` síncronas a código asícrono, y es que que los navegadores ya no soportan peticiones síncronas en el hilo principal, "debido a sus efectos de detrimento de la experiencia de usuario".

Comment: Tu última oración no debería tomarse como una respuesta, sino más bien un comentario, pues estás pidiendo información al OP. Por favor revisa [answer].

Comment: Recibido, gracias.